# how to set flash error in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I'm doin some simple app,i't gonna be some kind of translation app,so i have a search option and adding translations option.I have a problem with my search.When I click on search without any word there,it's shows me a list of translations.i would like to have a flash error there,like a i have it,when i look for a word which is not in database.

my model

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base


attr_accessible :text_english, :text_polish
validates_presence_of :text_english, :text_polish
validates :text_polish, :text_english, :uniqueness => true
 def self.search(search)
    if search
      where("text_english LIKE ? OR text_polish LIKE ?", "%#{search.strip}%", "%#{search.strip}%")
    else
        scooped
    end
  end
end
```

in my controller

```
# GET /translations/search
 def search
   @translations = Translation.search(params[:search])
   if !@translations.empty?
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
     end
   else
     flash[:error] = "NO TRANSLATIONS"
     redirect_to new_translation_url
   end
  end
end
```

and my search form in index

```
<h1>Words</h1>
<%= form_tag search_translations_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button> 
 <% end %>
```

thanx for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options, one that is fairly simple would be to add a couple of lines to your controller to account for no params[:search]

```
# GET /translations/search
 def search
   if params[:search].blank?
     flash[:error] = "A WORD TO TRANSLATE IS REQUIRED"
     redirect_to new_translation_url
   else
     @translations = Translation.search(params[:search])
     if !@translations.empty?
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html
       end
     else
       flash[:error] = "NO TRANSLATIONS"
       redirect_to new_translation_url
     end
   end
 end
```

The important thing to remember is to not allow any path in your code that could redirect or render twice. Hence the `if params[:search].blank? .. else`

Comment: I'd recommend `redirect_to SOME_PATH, :flash => { :error => "SOMETHING" }`, a bit cleaner.